# Event on named range creation in Excel using VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, events, vsto, ms-office

Is there any way to hook into the creation of a named range or list object in Excel 2007 using VSTO? I need to track the named ranges in a worksheet and, as such, need to be alerted when a new one is created.

I have tried the SheetChange and SheetCalculate events and neither is triggered on the creation of a new named range.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SheetSelectionChange event, and check if amount of named ranges changed.

```
void SheetSelectionChangeHandle(object Sheet, Range Target)
{
   if ((Worksheet)Sheet.Names.Count != oldNamedRangeCount)
   {
      oldNamedRangeCount = (Worksheet)Sheet.Names.Count;
      // Do stuff related to NamedRangeCountChanged
   }
}
```